# This song is sick. I knew you were trouble when you walked in?

Tags: grammar

Dont you think it should have been i knew you were 'troubled' when you walked in?

Or does it mean something else that i dont know?

Answer (score 1):

"Trouble" means that "you" are trouble, which means that you are causing problems.

"Troubled" means that "you" are troubled, which means "showing distress or anxiety" (New Oxford American Dictionary).